# What Are Good Solutions for a Database Table that Gets to Long?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, performance, architecture

I will describe a problem using a specific scenario:

Imagine that you create a website towhich users can register,
and after they register, they can send Private Messages to each other.

This website enables every user to maintain his own **Friends list**,
and also maintain a **Blocked Users list**, from which he prefers not to get messages.

Now the problem:

Imagine this website getting to several millions of users,
and let's also assume that every user has about 10 Friends in the Friends table, and 10 Blocked Users in the Blocked Users table.

The Friends list Table, and the Blocked Users table, will become very long,
but worse than that, every time when someone wants to send a message to another person "X",
we need to go over the whole Blocked Users table, and look for records that the user "X" defined - people he blocked.

This "scanning" of a long database table, each time a message is sent from one user to another, seems quite inefficient to me.

So I have 2 questions about it:

1. What are possible solutions for this problem?
   I am not afraid of long database tables,
   but I am afraid of database tables that contain data for so many users,
   which means that the whole table needs to be scanned *every time*, just to pull out a few records from it for that specific user.
2. A specific solution that I have in my mind, and that I would like to ask about:
   One solution that I have in mind for this problem, is that every user that registers to the website, will have his own "mini-database" dynamically (and programmatically) created for him,
   that way the Friends table, an the Blocked Users table, will contain **only records for him**.
   This makes scanning those table very easy, because all the records are for him.
   Does this idea exist in Databases like MS-SQL Server, or MySQL? And If yes, is it a good solution for the described problem?
   (each user will have his own small database created for him, and of course there is also the main (common) database for all other data that is not user specific)

Thank you all

Comment: Learn about indexes and table partitioning.

Comment: Thank you all for interesting answers, I am reading abut these issues now in order to choose and then implement the most appropriate one.

Comment: OK I am having a difficulty in choosing between Partitioning and Indexing. Some of you recommended Partitioning, yet one of you(benjamin moskovits) said partitioning will not bring a big performance change. So can you please help me choose between the 2?

Comment: How "big" do you expect?  A million rows in a table is pretty 'normal'.  A billion rows is somewhat challenging.

Comment: Hi Rick. Please note that the problem with a big table is not in terms of storage, it's due to the fact that every message that is being sent between 2 users in this website, requires scanning **the whole** Blocked Users table, before allowing the message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wait on the partitioning and on creating mini-database idea. Is your database installed with the data, log and temp files on different RAID drives? Do you have clustered indexes on the tables and indexes on the search and join columns?

Have you tried any kind of reading Query Plans to see how and where the slowdowns are occurring? Don't just add memory or try advanced features blindly before doing the basics.

Creating separate databases will become a maintenance nightmare and it will be challenging to do the type of queries (for all users....) that you will probably like to do in the future.

Partitioning is a wonderful feature of SQL Server and while in 2014 you can have thousands of partitions you probably (unless you put each partition on a separate drive) won't see the big performance bump you are looking for.

SQL Server has very fast response time for tables (especially for tables with 10s of millions of rows (in your case the user table)). Don't let the main table get too wide and the response time will be extremely fast.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. Can you please tell me why partitioning won't really help? The problem with this long table is not that it's long,.but the way we use it: unlike other long tables where we store data and read it once in a while, in this table we read it many many times a day, and in each read we need to scan all of it, because the table cantains multiple records for a user...(so we can't stop the scanning after finding a matching row, we need to go over all of them till the end of the table) because of this, any way we can reduce the scan length, will help..

Comment: If you create a primary key by user it will very quickly read all the rows for that user.. If you have thousands of users, partitioning will result in longer access times. Partitioning is great if you divide orders by year and/or month but in your case you probably cannot even create enough partitions for 100,000s of users. There is no magical solution for what you need to do. You need to read up on how to install SQL Server properly, get the right hardware setup (RAID is really, really important), find out where to put what and get your tables indexed correctly and into 3rd order form

Comment: You can partition if you do it by the first letter of each clients name (so you will have 26 partitions) but I would explore the other points before I get into partitioning. And please backup your database......

Comment: Yes, partitioning can be done by the first letter of the Username(26 partitions), or by the first digit of the UserID(10 partitions). If it's really big then we can even make it according to the first 2 digits of the UserID, so we get 100 partitions... - so we can create partitions in a reasonable number of divisions, we don't need to make a partition for every user.. so in that case will you consider it a good method?

Comment: I would try the other suggestions first and then see if partitioning adds value.

Comment: Naive partitioning is shifting from an INDEX to selecting a PARTITION -- for _zero_ gain in performance.  I have found _only_ 4 use cases where PARTITIONing gives any significant performance gain, [see my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: Spaceman - its customary to accept an answer so users are encouraged to keep answering. In my experience unless one places the different partitions on different RAID LUNs there is little performance gains seen. Its become a mantra for large tables, that are slow, partition but try first.....

Comment: Rick James: Thank you for the link to the blog - very interesting.

Comment: Rick - I apologize but I did not see any articles that mention measuring performance of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat my first thought is this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx

Partitioning can allow you to break it up into more manageable pieces and in a way that can be scalable.  There will be some choices you have to make about how you break it up, but I believe this is the right path for you.

In regards to table scanning if you have proper indexing you should be getting seeks in your queries.  You will want to look at execution plans to know for sure on this though.

As for having mini-DB for each user that is sort of what you can accomplish with partitioning.

Comment: Certainly.  I also want to add that I agree with other answers that if you have not explored normalizing the data as well as index utilization then those things are where you should start.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Mini-Database` for each user is a definite no-go zone.
2. Plus on a side note A separate table to hold just Two columns `UserID` and `BlockedUserID` both being `INT` columns and having correct indexes, you cannot go wrong with this approach , if you write your queries sensibly :)
3. look into table partitioning , also a well normalized database with decent indexes will also help.
4. Also if you can afford Enterprise Licence table partitioning with the table schema described in last point will make it a very good , query friendly database schema.

Comment: Thank you M.Ali. Can I please ask you, regarding #2, "having correct indexes" - what would be the recommended type of indexes to use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I did it once for a social network system. Maybe you can look for your normalization. At the time I got a [Relationship] table and it just got

```
UserAId  Int
UserBId  Int
RelationshipFlag  Smallint
```

With 1 million users and each one with 10 "friends" that table got 10 millions rows. Not a problem since we put indexes on the columns and it can retrieve a list of all "related" usersB to a specific userA in no time.

Take a good look on your schema and your indexes, if they are ok you DB ill not got problems handling it.

**Edit**

I agree with @M.Ali

> Mini-Database for each user is a definite no-go zone.

IMHO you are fine if you stick with the basic and implement it the right way